# Using multiple IF/AND statements to look at a query table and display a Yes/No result

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, report, multiple-columns

I'm attempting to write a formula for excel that will look at 3 different columns of data in a query table that I'm pulling from my teams sharepoint site. I'm trying to have a Yes/No result given.

The formula I've written so far is

=IF(AND(ISTEXT(Governance_Master_List__2[Is the check c]="Yes")+(AND(ISTEXT(Governance_Master_List__2[Merged Month and Year Due]="January 2023")+(AND(ISTEXT(Governance_Master_List__2[Frequency]="Weekly")))))),"Yes","No")

So, In this example I want the formula to look at [Is the check c] for a "Yes", then Look at the [Merged month and year due] for January 2023, and then look at [Frequency] for "Weekly", and if all 3 of those are met to show the result of Yes onto another worksheet.

So far the formula isn't throwing an error when making it, but it only returns the No result, even when I ensure that all the Weekly, January 2023 entries are showing as Yes.

I'm very new to excel in terms of formulas and am learning as I go. I feel like, because the refernce query table i'm looking at has tons of different values (eg, the frequency has weekly, 6 monthly, monthly, quarterly etc and that there are 12 months to choose from) that the formula is stopping because its looking at and not ignoring those other options, hence the constant false result.

I've tried the following variations with no result..

=IF(AND(ISTEXT(Governance_Master_List__2[Is the check c]="Yes")*(AND(ISTEXT(Governance_Master_List__2[Merged Month and Year Due]="January 2023")*(AND(ISTEXT(Governance_Master_List__2[Frequency]="Weekly")))))),"Yes","No")

=IF(AND('Imported data'!C1:C200="Weekly")+(AND('Imported data'!E1:E200="January 2023")+(AND('Imported data'!H1:H200="Yes"))),"Yes","No")

=IF(AND('Imported data'!C1:C200="Weekly")*(AND('Imported data'!E1:E200="January 2023")*(AND('Imported data'!H1:H200="Yes"))),"Yes","No")

The output excel sheet is to show our quarterly compliance reporting, i'm simple trying to automate the process of entering the data into that report, as the teams use a sharepoint list to enter their compliance tasks.

Anyone have a suggestion on how I can get this working? Eventually it'll be used to populate a number of different yes/no report cells based on the relevant month and frequency of the check.

Comment: `=IF(AND(Governance_Master_List__2[Is the check c]="Yes",Governance_Master_List__2[Merged Month and Year Due]="January 2023",Governance_Master_List__2[Frequency]="Weekly"),"Yes","No")`

Comment: `AND` requires comma separated conditions, not single conditions. Also `ISTEXT` is used to verify if cell value is text value and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not the cell value. Just reference the cell itself for that.

Comment: Still the same issue, the formula is still only returning the false value.

Comment: I see, they're not cells, but ranges. In that case we need samples of how the data is structured. It now requires each cell in given ranges to meet it's condition

Comment: If you have Office 365 you can use `=(Governance_Master_List__2[Is the check c]="Yes")*(Governance_Master_List__2[Merged Month and Year Due]="January 2023")*(Governance_Master_List__2[Frequency]="Weekly")` to spill the result (`TRUE` or `FALSE` for each condition met per row).